# Different robots.txt for staging server on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gitignore

I have staging and production apps on Heroku.

For crawler, I set robots.txt file.

After that I got message from Google.

> Dear Webmaster, The host name of your site, https://www.myapp.com/,
>   does not match any of the "Subject Names" in your SSL certificate, which were:
>   *.herokuapp.com
>   herokuapp.com

The Google bot read the robots.txt on my staging apps and send this message. because I didn't set anything for preventing crawlers to read the file.

So, what I'm thinking about is to change .gitignore file between staging and production, but I can't figure out how to do this.

What are the best practices for implementing this?

**EDIT**

I googled about this and found this article http://goo.gl/2ZHal

This article says to set basic Rack authentication and you won't need to care about robots.txt.

I didn't know that basic auth can prevent google bot.
It seems this solution is better that manipulate .gitignore file.

Comment: If git is the way you want to go, you could maintain a `staging` **branch** with the modified `.gitignore`, and push that branch to the staging site on heroku.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still new to git and need to learn more about branch, check about that method. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about serving `/robots.txt` dynamically using a controller action instead of having a static file?
Depending on the environment you allow or disallow search engines to index your application.

Comment: I searched about that and found several resources, I will try that. Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 13):

A great solution with Rails 3 is to use Rack. Here is a great post that outlines the process: [Serving Different Robots.txt Using Rack](http://avandamiri.com/2011/10/11/serving-different-robots-using-rack.html). To summarize, you add this to your routes.rb:

```
 # config/routes.rb
 require 'robots_generator' # Rails 3 does not autoload files in lib 
 match "/robots.txt" => RobotsGenerator
```

and then create a new file inside lib/robots_generator.rb

```
# lib/robots_generator.rb
class RobotsGenerator
  # Use the config/robots.txt in production.
  # Disallow everything for all other environments.
  # http://avandamiri.com/2011/10/11/serving-different-robots-using-rack.html
  def self.call(env)
    body = if Rails.env.production?
      File.read Rails.root.join('config', 'robots.txt')
    else
      "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /"
    end

    # Heroku can cache content for free using Varnish.
    headers = { 'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{1.month.seconds.to_i}" }

    [200, headers, [body]]
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
    [404, {}, ['# A robots.txt is not configured']]
  end
end
```

Finally make sure to include move robots.txt into your config folder (or wherever you specify in your `RobotsGenerator` class).

Comment: actually the article says to put the file in lib/robots_generator.rb, also move robots.txt from public/ to config/

Comment: This is quite an old thread, but can someone tell me why you'd use this solution over just a rails controller? Is it more performant or something?

Comment: @dkniffin Rack is great if you have some generic functionality that you might want to de-coupled from your application code. It can also be reused in different rack apps (like sinatra), but a rails controller is great solution too.

Comment: I think a staging environment should actually use `RAILS_ENV=production` to keep it as close to production as possible - so instead of checking for `Rails.env.production?`, you should add an ENV var to your staging server like `ROBOTS=disallow` and check for that instead.