# How to prevent an Heroku app from Google indexing?

Tags: heroku

Inspite of searches, I didn't find a final answer to this.

I have 2 apps in Heroku:

- myapp-stagging.herokuapp.com
- myapp-with-real-domain-name.com

These 2 apps have no content for now (there are not indexed in Google)

Before pushing content to them, I'd like to be sure that my stagging app will be not indexed in Google.
What is the right way to do it?
I don't understand because people talks about robots.txt but where am I supposed to write this file?

Thanks.

PS : is SO the right StackExchange site to ask this? Sorry if not.

Answer (score 5):

I found a similar question on Webmasters StackExchange: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/65378/31283

You could add a [link rel canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) on every page of your app.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://myapp-with-real-domain-name.com" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look for complete instruction here - http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

> It works likes this: a robot wants to vists a Web site URL, say
>   http://www.example.com/welcome.html. Before it does so, it firsts
>   checks for http://www.example.com/robots.txt

I guess it give you idea where to place robots.txt

Comment: Thanks for this! But how to deal with several environments with one robots.txt file on Heroku? Is there a way to create 2 files ? Or should I use environment variables in Heroku? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813534/different-robots-txt-for-staging-server-on-heroku -> this sounds promising :)

Comment: don't get you. what does it mean by several env with one robots.txt? my bet is that you need to place on robot txt on staging and one on real app

Comment: Heroku doesn't work like that. You have the same files for all your environments. But you can deals with env vars. I created dynamic robots.txt according to env var, seems to work :)